# Automation to multiple SSH through paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, paramiko

I'm pretty new to Paramiko library.

I have a text file which has list of [ipaddress1, string1], [ipaddress2, string2], [ipaddress3, string3].
And every ipaddress is the RPi server behind it.

I want to make SSH connection to each ip address and copy the string to a file located in corresponding RPi.

So basically, the string for example "abc" should be written to the file xyz.yaml inside RPi (/home/pi/).

How do I do this particular automation. It will be great to receive support.

Below is the code snippet to connect to one server, How do I make changes to connect to multiple servers at same time and perform the above task:

```
    import sys
import time
import paramiko
import getpass

my_id = "id"
my_password = "pass"
port = "17455"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
in_file = []
out_file = open('connection_results.txt', 'w')
in_file = open('list_of_servers.txt', 'r')
print(in_file)
for server in in_file:
    print("first host", server)
    hosts = server.split(',')
    for host in hosts:
        print("Checking server", host)
        time.sleep(3)
        try:
            print(host, my_id, my_password, port)
            ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=my_id,
    

                password=my_password, port=port)

        terminal = ssh.invoke_shell()
        # terminal.send('junk')
        terminal.send('\n')
        time.sleep(2)
        output = terminal.recv(10240)
        # print(output)

        command = 'hostname'

        (stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command(command)

        for line in stdout.readlines():
            print("Connected to", line)
            out_file.write("connected to " + line + "\n")

        terminal.send('exit')
        terminal.send('\n')
        time.sleep(2)

        ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

        with ftp.open('/home/men/testingnew.py', 'r+') as file:
            read_file = file.read()
            read_file = read_file.replace(
                "unique_id", "AZUre_IOT_adsfdfdf")
            print("File read")
        with ftp.open('/home/men/testingnew.py', "w") as file:
            file.write(read_file)
            
            print('Written to file')
            f.flush()
            ftp.close()
            ssh.close()

    except:
        out_file.write("Could not connect to " + host + "\n")


in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Oh sorry I really didnt think that thru, I have been working with one server and paramiko library, I have copied here as well. Sorry I couldnt make further changes.

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl I have made some changes, and further development, here it goes to the server and I  checked  the append file which it works, but I want to read this file and replace a  particular string, but it isnt working thru the sftp paramiko  function, could u help me ?

Comment: Sure @MartinPrikryl I have resolved the error and i was related to something else (decode and rstrip of string was required), not indentation.
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by adding decode and rstrip after reading the file:

```
import sys
import time
import paramiko
import getpass

my_id = "id"
my_password = "pass"
port = "17455"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
in_file = []
out_file = open('connection_results.txt', 'w')
in_file = open('list_of_servers.txt', 'r')
print(in_file)
for server in in_file:
    print("first host", server)
    hosts = server.split(',')
    for host in hosts:
        print("Checking server", host)
        time.sleep(3)
        try:
            print(host, my_id, my_password, port)
            ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=my_id,
    

            password=my_password, port=port)

    terminal = ssh.invoke_shell()
    # terminal.send('junk')
    terminal.send('\n')
    time.sleep(2)
    output = terminal.recv(10240)
    # print(output)

    command = 'hostname'

    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command(command)

    for line in stdout.readlines():
        print("Connected to", line)
        out_file.write("connected to " + line + "\n")

    terminal.send('exit')
    terminal.send('\n')
    time.sleep(2)

    ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

    with ftp.open('/home/men/testingnew.py', 'r+') as file:
        read_file = file.read().decode('utf-8').rstrip('/n')

        read_file = read_file.replace(
            "unique_id", "AZUre_IOT_adsfdfdf")
        print("File read")
    with ftp.open('/home/men/testingnew.py', "w") as file:
        file.write(read_file)
        
        print('Written to file')
        f.flush()
        ftp.close()
        ssh.close()

except:
    out_file.write("Could not connect to " + host + "\n")


in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```